# Perl download of binary file from (a GitHub) URL with HTTPS and redirect

Tags: perl, redirect, github, https

I am attempting to download a binary file hosted on [github.com](http://github.com) to the local disk. The context requires I do this in Perl. Here's my test code:

```
use File::Fetch;

$fileurl = "https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/archive/6.13.zip";
$to = "/tmp";

$ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => "$fileurl") || die("Fetch failed\n");

print STDERR "Fetch->new succeeded\n";

$where = $ff->fetch(to => $to);

if ($where) {
    print STDERR "Fetched file to '$where'\n";
}
else {
    print STDERR "Fetch failed: " . $ff->error(1) . "\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

This worked fine downloading a test file from my non-*GitHub*, mock-up web-server serving over HTTP. For the file hosted on *GitHub*, however, it fails with no illuminating error messages:

```
% ./trydownload
Fetch->new succeeded
Fetch failed:
%
```

For [github.com](http://github.com), the above approach appears to have two problems:

1. It apparently does not support the HTTPS download offered by *GitHub*
2. It apparently does not follow the redirect *GitHub* seems to use to direct the client to the actual storage location of the file

Internet searches turn up a veritable maze of components and pieces with which I could (I presume) eventually construct a working solution. I do not have days to experiment with getting all these assembled properly, however.

Does someone know the cut-and-dried answer to how to make the above code, or equivalent in Perl, download a binary file through HTTPS and an apparent redirect? Or at least succeed at the download from [github.com](http://github.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same using the libcurl wrapper `WWW::Curl::Easy;`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;

my ($out, $filename) = tempfile();

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/archive/6.13.zip");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, $out);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
my $retcode = $curl->perform();

if ($retcode != 0) {
  print STDERR  "Fetch Failed: ", $curl->strerror($retcode), " ( +$retcode)\n";
  print STDERR  "errbuf: ", $curl->errbuf;
  exit(1);
} 
else {
  print STDERR  "Fetched file to: ", $filename, "\n";
}
```